# Sending Google Analytics ECommerce transaction using C#

Tags: c#, google-analytics-api

I have an ecommerce application and I want to send each transaction made to the google analytics.
I have seen many examples doing it using Js but I have a pipeline in my application that sends all the successful transactions to Magento and I want to use that pipeline to also send the data to Google Analytics.

Are there any C# code samples for that a some guides to show it how it can be done?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/). Using this API you'll be able to send basic http requests to record common hit types in your Google Analytics profile. Specifically, you'll need to look at the call for [transaction hit](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide).